# R Data Frame Sorted by Variable Returns One Row

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to sort a data frame by a column that comes from a function call. I created a series of if statements to assign the proper column name to the outcol variable:

```
if (outmeasure == "heart attack") {
        outcol <- "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack"
    } else if (outmeasure == "heart failure") {
        outcol <- "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Failure"
    } else if (outmeasure == "pneumonia") {
        outcol <- "Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Pneumonia"
```

Ordering my data frame by any of the above column name works:

```
temp <- temp[with(temp, order(Hospital.30.Day.Death..Mortality..Rates.from.Heart.Attack)), ]
```

[image: Data frame ordered by column name]

But I need to use the variable outcol, which returns one (unsorted) row:

```
temp <- temp[with(temp, order(outcol)), ]
```

[image: one row returned]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(col1 =c(3896,3900,3899,3903), mortality.rate= c(15.7,12.9,15.7,16.0))
df
df[with(df,order(mortality.rate)),]
outcol <- "mortality.rate"
df[order(df[outcol]),]
```